# How to split a dataset (CSV) into training and test data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

How to split a dataset (CSV) into training and test data in Python programming language if there are no dependent variables in it?

The project I am currently working on is machine learning based and the dataset does not contain any dependent data. The following code works only if the dataset contains a dependent data-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

I expect the split to happen without any `y` variable.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of "random" distribution.
1) 100% random
2) 'random' but 'equal' distribution of data (i.e. same means / norms)

To answer your question, I would first recommend using a package for managing your data frames (i.e. Pandas)

see link for info:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

So, if you wanted to get a random 50% sample of the DataFrame with replacement:

```
 df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1)
```

Comment: How do i get the other 50% of the dataframe stored in another variable

Answer (score 0):

To split the dataset into train and test sets, we could shuffle the entire dataset first and slice it out based on the required size.

```
import pandas as pd
shuffle = df.sample(frac=1)

train_size = int(0.8 * len(df))

train = shuffle[:train_size]
test = shuffle[train_size:]
```